# jq sort using the value of a nested array element

Tags: json, jq

I need some help using `jq` to sort an array of elements where each element contains a nested 
`tags` array of elements. My input JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "ct-1",
      "tags": [
        {
          "key": "service_name",
          "value": "BaseCT"
        },
        {
          "key": "sequence",
          "value": "bb"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ct-2",
      "tags": [
        {
          "key": "service_name",
          "value": "BaseCT"
        },
        {
          "key": "sequence",
          "value": "aa"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to sort using the value of the `sequence` tag in the nested `tags` array so that the output looks like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "ct-2",
      "tags": [
        {
          "key": "service_name",
          "value": "BaseCT"
        },
        {
          "key": "sequence",
          "value": "aa"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ct-1",
      "tags": [
        {
          "key": "service_name",
          "value": "BaseCT"
        },
        {
          "key": "sequence",
          "value": "bb"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following `jq` command:

```
$ jq '.result |= ([.[] | .tags[] | select(.key == "sequence") | .value] | sort_by(.))' input.json
```

but I get the following result:

```
{
  "result": [
    "aa",
    "bb"
   ]
}
```

Please let me know if you know how to deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`from_entries` converts an array of key-value pairs to an object, you can use it with `sort_by` like this:

```
.result |= sort_by(.tags | from_entries | .sequence)
```